# Second Monitor disappeared in Kubuntu 22.10

Tags: linux, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, kde, kubuntu

I am currently having an issue with my second monior on Kubuntu. I don't know if this is relevant but its an ultrawide monitor (5120x1440). Everything was working well and fine up until this morning now my behaviour is this.

- xrandr -q does not show the second monitor
- lspci | grep VGA shows both the integrated and dedicated Graphics Card
- The prompt to choose how to use the second monitor (extend to left, right etc.) shows up but selecting does not change anything
- it seems like in the display configuration for a quarter of a second the preferences for a second monitor show up but dissapear right again
- Windows (I have a dual boot system) shows now issues

Now I have been using Linux for a while now on the server side but am still pretty new to the graphical user interface. So I have difficulties choosing what information/logs might be helpful here and where to find them but I'd be happy to supply any additional information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was an update with the newest nvidia drivers. I downgraded from 525 back to 515 and everything seems to be working ok again. Just to be sure I also purged and reinstalled the intel drivers.